# Axis 1.4 generating too many parameters in the constructor

Tags: axis

I am using the Axis 1.4 wsdl2java tool to generate stub java classes for [this wsdl](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2011_1_0/netsuite.wsdl/)

The problem is the tool generates a constructor in TransactionSearchBasic that exceeds Java's limit of 255.  I need a way to instruct the wsdl2java tool not generate that large of a constructor.  So I know that using a jaxb binding of:

`<jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="2000"/>`

works for the CFX client generation, but I need a way to get the generate source correct from the axis wsdl2java client.  Is there a way to specify the typeSafeEnumMaxMembers in the wsdl2java client in Axis?

Comment: Do you really need to use Axis 1.x?

Comment: I think so.  I was getting errors (granted this was a long time ago) with the cfx generated classes

Comment: I suggest trying harder.  Axis 1.x is a nightmare.  Show us the errors you get with CXF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this problem in the past. In my case I had no choice but to use Axis 1.x because I needed to generate code stubs from a RPC/encoded WSDL file -  a format which is not supported in version 2.

I got around the issue by taking the Axis 1.4 source code and applying a fix (I forget where I found the fix) for the issue. I stuck it in a GitHub repository at:
https://github.com/zephyrj/JAxis-1.4.5